# How to build workflows with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a desktop application and use `Spring` a lot.

Now I wonder if there is any good approach to organize workflow executions against a webservice?

Example usecase: the user wants to book a car.

Therefore, my application would have to perform the following workflow. But not at once, as between the request the obtained data must be displayed to the user and wait for further interaction:

```
   authenticate 
-> search for a list of cars 
-> return result to user
-> pick a specific car 
-> return details of the car
-> enter credit card payment data 
-> book the car 
-> display confirmation
```

Also, at any time the user should of course have the chance to cancel the workflow and start all over.

Is there any *non-xml* approach in Spring (or different java framework) that can help creating and maintaining such workflows?

Comment: Try this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html                                                      But this is not a non-xml approach.

Comment: @Prasad webflow is for web-based apps, but I think OP wants something for desktop apps.

Comment: Ah oversight on desktop part!